# speed up replace NaNs with last non-Nan value

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop

I'd like to replace all the NaNs in a vector with the last previous non-NaN value

```
input =  [1 2 3 NaN NaN 2];
output = [1 2 3 3   3   2];
```

i'd like to try and speed up the loop I already have

```
input = [1 2 3 NaN NaN 2];

if isnan(input(1))
    input(1) = 0;
end

for i= 2:numel(input)
    if isnan(input(i))
        input(i) = input(i-1);
    end
end
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How slow is it? This is the particular kind of operation in Matlab I have trouble thinking of how to vectorise, I'd be interested if there are faster solutions. As far as I know, this is probably the most efficient. Have you checked with `profile` if this is where you slowdown happens? I guess the only thing I can think of is to computer a `nans` vector using `nans=isnan(input);` first, and use `if (nans(i))` instead of `if isnan(input(i))`, as it would use less function calls? Not sure if it's any better.

Comment: yup that speeds it up a fair bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the previous non-NaN value, I'll assume that the first value must be a number.

```
while(any(isnan(input)))
    input(isnan(input)) = input(find(isnan(input))-1);
end
```

I profiled dylan's solution, Oleg's solution, and mine on a 47.7 million long vector.  The times were 12.3s for dylan, 3.7 for Oleg, and 1.9 for mine.

Comment: nice. although this solution slows down a bit when there are more nans. At ~0.5 or so it is he same speed or faster as the for loop version with Hugh's addition

Answer (score 0):

Here a commented solution, works for a vector only but might be enxtended to work on a matrix:

```
A = [NaN NaN 1 2 3 NaN NaN 2 NaN NaN NaN 3 NaN 5 NaN NaN];

% start/end positions of NaN sequences
sten = diff([0 isnan(A) 0]);
B    = [NaN A];
% replace with previous non NaN
B(sten == -1) = B(sten == 1);
% Trim first value (previously padded)
B = B(2:end);
```

Comparison

```
A: NaN NaN 1 2 3 NaN NaN 2 NaN NaN NaN 3 NaN 5 NaN NaN
B: NaN NaN 1 2 3 NaN   3 2 NaN NaN   2 3   3 5 NaN   5
```

Comment: This looks good, although all previous NaNs should be overwritten not just the first one. I can't think of a way to do it other than looping over the expression

Answer (score 0):

Not fully vectorized but quite simple and probably still fairly efficient:

```
x = [1 2 3 NaN NaN 2];
for f = find(isnan(x))
    x(f)=x(f-1);
end
```

Of course this is only slightly different than the solution provided by @Hugh Nolan

Answer (score -1):

```
nan_ind = find(isnan(A)==1);
A(nan_ind) = A(nan_ind-1);
```